# How to get this question re-opened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Recently this [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135825/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-sharing-personal-dream-sequences-with-t) was asked: "Should I share personal dream sequences with the party as a DM?"

Clearly as a "should I" question it was inherently opinion based and was closed. However I think the topic and concept could get some excellent answers.

I edited the question to ["What are the advantages/disadvantages of sharing personal dream sequences with the party?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135825/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-sharing-personal-dream-sequences-with-t) in an attempt to make it less opinion-based and get it reopened.

**Is there anything else I can do without action from the asker to get this opened?**

Full disclosure: I have good personal experience on the topic and feel I could post a high quality answer to that question.

Comment: Note: the question has since been reopened.

Comment: @V2Blast Yes. Thankyou, I have also posted my answer there. What should I do with this question? Close or delete?

Comment: You didn't ask me, but I suggest you leave this question here. The topic of *Should I* questions *generally* should be addressed in answer to this question, and that's important.