# Can I ask a question on published designer intent?

Tags: support, specific-question, questions

In a lot of answers, it would be helpful to explain why things are working as they are.  For example that 5e is designed to leave much more to DM adjuction [than earlier versions](https://www.enworld.org/threads/mearls-on-d-ds-design-premises-goals.665731/), because trying to cover all cases by the rules leads to rules bloat and makes the game hard to play. The games designers have gone on record about what is driving several design decisions in interviews and posts like that one linked. Would it be OK to ask a question about the published design principles for the game? If we had a solid answer to this question, we could then easily point to it in other answers.

The question could be

### What are major design goals for D&D 5e?

D&D 5e differes from its direct predecessors, D&D 3.5e and D&D 4e in several ways, for example,

- it puts a lot more emphasis on the DM in adjucating rules, and on keeping the core rules relatively small.
- it aims to use **bounded accuracy** to limit the scale of bonus progressions to a more narrow band
- it aims to speed up play and limit admisitrateive overhead by limiting the number of effects player charactes can have at the same time with rules like *concentration* and *attunement*

What where the major design goals for 5e, as published in commentary by the game's designers?

Comment: Your question about 5e design is probably a duplicate of this question:[Are the design goals for 5e currently available?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76327/62294).

Comment: As a side note, a few years back I had a thought to pull together such a Q&A. I never got around to it, but if you want to try I've got saved somewhere the links to all the old Legends & Lore articles (via wayback) where Cook and Mearls and Thompson (IIRC) talked a *lot* about what the thoughts were at each step of design and then Next.

Comment: @nitsua60 Answering the question directly with “go ahead, I’ve got some of the resources” is not a “side note” and should be written as an answer to be properly voted on.

Comment: Just a note given the wording: _every_ question about designer intent is/was a question about _published_ designer intent. Otherwise there's nothing to back up your answer as true instead of fabricated/speculative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Right now, no

Everything [designer-intent](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/designer-intent) is currently [banned](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7964/4563). Note that this was a decision made after a period of problem with these questions—even though we **always** required them to be backed up with published developer statements. So asking for that still falls under the ban.

That ban, however, is [currently being debated](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11951/4563), with strong support for either weakening or removing the ban.

Comment: This is probably the right take on the simple question "is this on topic according to current practice". However, I think there is a more interesting exploration to be done: *does a question like the one described face the same challenges as the more typical rule intent questions?* That is, questions of the form "X rule is causing Y problem, what did the authors intend for this rule?" I'm not sure that the question form offered by Groody above has all the same issues, but maybe has some of them. What do you think, KRyan?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov That’s totally valid, but splitting that discussion into another question when we have an active and featured discussion on the topic as a whole seems incorrect. I’d rather see that pitched as an answer to the existing discussion if that was the intent. Also, I’d point out that such why-did-they-write-this-rule questions *usually* received dubious reviews even before the designer-intent ban, so they’re a little tangential to the ban itself IMO. The ban was “yeah, we have to ban these, _even then_, because no matter how much we insist on things being backed up they just aren’t.”